# Pybind callback function generation

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++14, pybind11

I am writing Python binding code for a C++ function:

```
void cls::acceptCall(My::namespace::Reply reply)
{
    std::cout <<__FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    reply(My::namespace::Result::Ok, nullptr);
}
using Reply = std::function<void(Result result, std::exception_ptr error)>;
enum class Result {Ok,NOT_OK }
```

bind code:

```
py::class_<APIExtProvider>(m, "APIExtProvider")
    .def("acceptCall", &APIExtProvider::acceptCall, py::call_guard<py::gil_scoped_release>())
```

python_call:

```
result = pyunifiedphone.Result.OK
exception = pyunifiedphone.Exception()

def reply_method(result, exception):
    return None
     
 provider.acceptCall(reply_method)
```

However, I get this error:

TypeError: acceptCall(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (self: pyunifiedphone.APIExtProvider, arg1: Callable[[pyunifiedphone.Result, pyunifiedphone.Exception], None]) -> None

Invoked with: <pyunifiedphone.APIExtProvider object at 0x7f2b6aa149b0>, , <function reply_method at 0x7f2b6abfa1f0>

What is the correct way of binding?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately pybind11 does not auto convert data types from c/c++ to python .
add this header files to your project and test again . if it did not work , you should convert your data to a bindable type .

```
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/chrono.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>
```